# Apache kafka server start binds to at path /brokers/ids/0 with addresses deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com:9092 instead of localhost

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to run apache kafka locally, the zookeeper is running fine and binds to port 2181 with the localhost. When I start kafka server, it fails with the following error. What could be the reason?

```
WARN [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Connection to node 0 
(a23-202-231-169.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com/23.202.231.169:9092)
could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Comment: Can you show the server configs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default in the Kafka properties, `listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092`, which will use the broker hostname. Change this to `listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092` if you only want local connections

For client connections, you'll also need to configure `advertised.listeners`, which controls the IP/hostname returned to clients

Comment: I have this server configuration on my other mac where it works perfectly fine without having to modify the listener config at all.

Comment: # The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

Comment: For the machine I had this issue, I changed as below as per your suggestion and it started working############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092